# Annoying triangle while customizing IKImageBrowserView group appearance

Tags: cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

I am trying to change the appearance of the group header of an IKImageBrowserView. I've seen that we can provide an custom CALayer with IKImageBrowserGroupHeaderLayer

> > [customizing IKImageBrowserView group appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268797/customizing-ikimagebrowserview-group-appearance)

but every time I do I get stuck with this little triangle that gets shown and NOT animated correctly

Do you have any pointer for this? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the triangle you could add?

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug
Screenshot of the annoying triangle: http://d.pr/i/9fdx

Comment: voted to close as this is not applicable today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be fixed Soon ... it was a bug in cocoa.
on an issue tracker Id close it :D

apple provided a workaround at the time of writing and in 10.8.2 it is fixed