# How to use IKImagebrowserView's group display?

Tags: grouping, ikimagebrowserview, ikimagekit

The effect I want is like the iPhoto group(or timeline) displaying.

[image]

I have already realized the common IKImageBrowserView. which is like 
[image]

But I don't know how to assign them in different groups.

I referred: [customizing IKImageBrowserView group appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268797/customizing-ikimagebrowserview-group-appearance), which is the only post in stackoverflow, maybe.

I used the 4 methods of `IKImageBrowserDataSource`.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInImageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)browser;
- (id)imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)browser itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSUInteger)numberOfGroupsInImageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)browser;
- (NSDictionary *)imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)browser groupAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

I think I don't know how to write code for the last 2 methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to implement those last two methods for groups to appear. If you simply want to see the effect, you can do something like this:

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfGroupsInImageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *) aBrowser
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSDictionary *) imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *) aBrowser groupAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index
{
    NSRange r = {0, 3};
    return @{IKImageBrowserGroupRangeKey: [NSValue valueWithRange:r],
             IKImageBrowserGroupBackgroundColorKey: [NSColor redColor],
             IKImageBrowserGroupStyleKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:IKGroupDisclosureStyle]};
}
```

The important key in the directory returned by groupAtIndex is `IKImageBrowserGroupRangeKey`. This describes what range of images are in a given group. Note that NSRange is a structure and is not derived from NSObject so it can't be used as a value in a dictionary. Hence, it must be converted to an NSValue.

For this to be truly useful you'll want to cache your set of range values and provide a mechanism for grouping and ungrouping images, but I hope this is enough to get you started

Comment: Thanks Dale. I can see the effect now. I'd like to ask more, I don't understand how the work flow goes. For example, I have several NSArray  (array1, array2, array3)to save the pictures' link. How can I see the thumbnails?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Have you built the ImageBrowser sample code project provided by Apple? You can get to it here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html). The example uses `IKImageBrowserPathRepresentationType` and simply provides paths. You might want to look at the IKImageBrowserItem Protocol Reference as well.

Comment: I referred [DesktopImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DesktopImage/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008860) and [ImageBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003997), but both are not related to group appearance.I hope you can keep answering my questions, I cannot find any other examples in Internet.