# IKImageBrowserView, collapse group will lose selection

Tags: cocoa, nsimageview, ikimagebrowserview

I asked a question before: [How to use IKImagebrowserView's group dispaly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901792/how-to-use-ikimagebrowserviews-group-dispaly)
And now I am got the group style view very well, like this
[image]

when I select some photos(not all of them) from group yazi, [image]

and then click the small triangle to collapse it, and click again to expand it, the selection is lost. I think it's the default action of IKImageBrowserView. 
Anyone knows what function will be called when I do the collapse/expand function.

Comment: Are you customize your IKImageBrowserView to group them or showing triangle for expending image. I need to add a buton on IKImageBrowserView Item, if you can help me then please help me.

Comment: I don't know how to add a button. I didn't customize it, the style I used is default.